# kineticjs - mouseover inaccurate

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseover, kineticjs

I'm building a polar graph visualisation that needs tooltips over its arcs. It works, except that the mouseover is imprecise: it is triggered by mousing over places with no shape, and does not get triggered when it should.

You can see it for yourself via my prototype on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLj3W/2/).

Any idea what i could do to fix that?

**UPDATE**

In fact, if i fill() the arcs, it shows the area that is really taking the event. It's perfectly responsive, although i guess i now need to find a way to make it not take into account the fill...

Comment: I'm not seeing any tooltips in FF13. Can you excerpt the specific parts dealing with the tooltip behavior and explain briefly how it works?

Comment: I've looked at it a few times, and in Chrome, and I don't see any tooltips, and I can't pick out where the tooltip part is added? Is that the right fiddle link?

Comment: @JaredFarrish sorry, indeed it was the wrong link. I've updated the question with the right link. Sorry again.

Answer (score 2):

You are drawing a line and thus you will only get an event in the middle of the line. Use instead shape

Comment: You may want to provide now details and close snippets. This answer doesn't seem to explain much .

Answer (score 0):

Filling the arcs show the real area (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLj3W/3/))). So it's completely accurate, though not the effect i need to achieve. But this question is solved °-)

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now. You either need a transparently "there" layer that accepts tooltip actions, or a way to fire a tooltip manually when over that area I suppose.